# DSNUTILB - DB2 SYSTEM DOES NOT EXIST

Tags: db2, mainframe, jcl, return-code

Hi I would like to ask what's wrong with my JCL code. I have been working on it for quite a while now. When I submit this, I get an RC 08 and it says the DSNUTILB - DB2 SYSTEM DOES NOT EXIST on the SYSPRINT. Can anyone help me out on this? Thanks. :)

Here's my JCL code:

```
//X544582L JOB (T,92958888P), 
// 'N=TSO.X544582', 
// CLASS=S, 
// MSGCLASS=H, 
// MSGLEVEL=(1,1), 
// REGION=32M, 
// NOTIFY=&SYSUID 
//* TYPRUN=SCAN 
//* 
//JOBLIB DD DSN=X544582.LOADLIB1,DISP=SHR 
//* 
//STEP001 EXEC PGM=DSNUTILB 
//STEPLIB DD DSN=DSN910.SDSNLOAD,DISP=SHR 
//SYSUT1 DD DSN=&&SYSUT1, 
// DISP=(MOD,DELETE,DELETE), 
// SPACE=(CYL,(10,10)) 
//SYSMAP DD DSN=&&SYSMAP, 
// DISP=(MOD,DELETE,DELETE), 
// SPACE=(CYL,(10,10)) 
//SORTOUT DD DSN=&&SORTOUT, 
// DISP=(MOD,DELETE,DELETE), 
// SPACE=(CYL,(10,10)) 
//LOADIN DD DSN=X544582.SIPROOT.PBB01,DISP=SHR 
//SYSIN DD * 
  LOAD DATA INDDN LOADIN 
  RESUME 
  INTO TABLE IMS2DB2.SIPROOT_PBB01_T 
  ( 
   STATION_NO INTEGER, 
   AIRLINE_CODE CHAR(2), 
   SIPROOT_DATA_01 CHAR(4) 
  ) 
/*                                               
//SYSPRINT DD SYSOUT=*
//SYSUDUMP DD SYSOUT=*
//SYSERR DD SYSOUT=*
//UTPRINT DD SYSOUT=*
//
```

Answer (score 1):

`DSNUTILB` has to have a `PARM` that includes the DB2 subsystem you're trying to access. See [this page](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_9.0.0/com.ibm.db2z9.doc.ugref/src/tpc/db2z_utlcreatejcldataset.dita) in the Information Center.

Basically, I think you need to add a line like this:

```
//         PARM='sub,id,',
```

Where `sub` is the subsystem ID, and `id` is a unique identifier for the utility run (in my shop, we usually use something like the JCL name, and what the step is doing, so maybe you could do something like `X544582L.LOAD`. You might check to see if your shop has a standard for this.